# Enabling/Disabling Mouse Pointer Precision in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, mouse

Does anyone know a way to enable/disable the Enhanced Mouse Pointer Precision (EPP) via command line?

I'm a gamer and installed a fix, http://donewmouseaccel.blogspot.nl/2010/03/markc-windows-7-mouse-acceleration-fix.html, only I would like to still have it enabled in Windows itself.

I have a Corsair Vengeance M95 gaming mouse, so it has advanced capabilities of macros.

Basically what I am trying is on one button: "Switch to gaming profile": First disable EPP, then switch to the Gaming Profile. And on the other button vica versa.

The EPP does not seem to be a registry value, so any clue how I would disable it... or achieve this functionality in another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enhance pointer precision setting can be changed via a call to the [windows API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). I wrote a small tool that does just that. You can find it on [github.io](http://jan-glx.github.io/accelSwitch/). 
The change takes effect immediately (If you check that it works via the mouse properties dialog, you have to reopen the dialog).